# NSolve takes too long time!

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following problem numerically and I faced two things: 1- It takes too long time to give solutions.
2- there are many roots for the equation but NSolve doesn't give all thee possible roots, it seems that it choose the first value that satisfy the equation!
The solutions should be as in the fig below

```
λ11 = (-k^2 + Sqrt[x^2 - ub1^2])^(1/2);
λ12 = (-k^2 - Sqrt[x^2 - ub1^2])^(1/2);
f11 = (I λ11 - k)^2/(x - ub1);
f12 = (I λ12 - k)^2/(x - ub1);
λ21 = (-k^2 + Sqrt[x^2 - ub2^2])^(1/2);
λ22 = (-k^2 - Sqrt[x^2 - ub2^2])^(1/2);
g21 = (I λ21 + k)^2/(x + ub2);
g22 = (I λ22 + k)^2/(x + ub2);

M = {{1, 1, -1, -1}, {f11, f12, -g21, -g22}, {λ11, λ12, λ21, λ22}, 
    {λ11 f11, λ12 f12, λ21 g21, λ22 g22}};    
ub1:=0.25;
ub2:=0.25;
Table[NSolve[{Det[M]==0},x,WorkingPrecision->4],{k,-1,1,0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The speed issue is resolved by computing `Det[M]`outside `Table`: For instance,  `s = Numerator[Det[M] // FullSimplify]` and `x /. Table[NSolve[s == 0, x], {k, -1, 1, 0.1}]`.  However, it may be necessary to use `FindRoot` to find all the roots.

Comment: @bb, the resulting equations will be algebraic, so I think `NSolve[]` can handle it (though preprocessing with `GroebnerBasis[]` might be needed).

Comment: @J.M.  Following you suggestion, as I understand it, I tried `First@GroebnerBasis[Det[M], x]` and was able to reproduce the curves in the question.  Unfortunately, the solutions do not for the most part satisfy `Det[M]==0`.  This and other attempts to obtain the curves lead me to believe that the equation in the question do not, in fact, yield these curves.

Comment: @bb, may you please show me how you obtain the curves using 'GroebnerBasis[]' with 'NSolve'. By the way the Det[M]=0 has analytic solutions which we can simply obtain using 'Solve' and they are the ones I plot above. However, I am trying to do it also numerically to verify that 'NSolve' can be used to investigate a system without analytic solution. For example when ub1 doesn't equal ub2.

Comment: Faster if given exact input, that is, use `ub1 = 1/4; ub2 = 1/4;` and `Table[NSolve[{Det[M] == 0}, x], {k, -1, 1, 1/10}]`. Not sure what is the bottleneck offhand, might have to do with removing the parasite solutions that arise from having the variables in radicals.

Comment: As requested, I added the `GroebnerBasis` plot.  Please add to your question the code that you used to create your plot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here is plot obtained using `GroebnerBasis` (suggested by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)).

```
ub1 = 1/4; ub2 = 1/4;
λ11 = (-k^2 + Sqrt[x^2 - ub1^2])^(1/2);
λ12 = (-k^2 - Sqrt[x^2 - ub1^2])^(1/2);
f11 = (I λ11 - k)^2/(x - ub1);
f12 = (I λ12 - k)^2/(x - ub1);
λ21 = (-k^2 + Sqrt[x^2 - ub2^2])^(1/2);
λ22 = (-k^2 - Sqrt[x^2 - ub2^2])^(1/2);
g21 = (I λ21 + k)^2/(x + ub2);
g22 = (I λ22 + k)^2/(x + ub2);
M = {{1, 1, -1, -1}, {f11, f12, -g21, -g22}, {λ11, λ12, λ21, λ22}, 
     {λ11 f11, λ12 f12, λ21 g21, λ22 g22}};

s = FullSimplify[Det[M]];
GroebnerBasis[s, x][[1]]
(* 1 - 256 k^4 + 16384 k^8 - 128 x^2 - 18432 k^4 x^2 - 262144 k^8 x^2 + 6144 x^4 + 
   393216 k^4 x^4 + 1048576 k^8 x^4 - 131072 x^6 - 2097152 k^4 x^6 + 1048576 x^8 *)
x /. Solve[% == 0, x] // Flatten;
Plot[Evaluate[%], {k, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {k, x}]
```

[image]

It differs from the figure in the question (apart from colors) by the presence short curve segments in the corners.  They can be eliminated, if desired, by using `Evaluate[%[[5;;8]]]` instead of `Evaluate[%]` in the final line of code.

Comment: These would be most likely from "parasite" solutions due to presence of radicals (probably you knew that but maybe it's not obvious to everyone).

Comment: @bb, In fact, I eliminated those curves at the corners since I was interested to find solution for `Abs[x]<0.4` and I forgot to add them to the plot in the question. I think we did the same thing, but I am interested to find these solutions using `NSolve` not `Solve`. As I mentioned earlier I would like to compare the results for `Solve` and `NSolve`